# Modal popup with single field rendering and functional, but not submitting?

Tags: python, html, django, modal-dialog

I have a form that keeps track of when a user enters/leaves an area and whenever there is a time discrepancy, it prompts the user for an estimate of a time.

Currently the main parts of the form work, and the modal shows up when it needs to, but when you try to submit the "edited timestamp" the modal just gets stuck on loading and nothing happens until you refresh the page, and even when you do, nothing has been submitted to the database for the edited timestamp. It just  stays with the loading symbol moving over the submit button like shown below:

[image]

What could be causing this to get stuck? Looking through the code (I'm not too familiar with python) I believe it has to do with not having a .save()/.update() for the field being modified (edited_timestamp), or maybe the redirection after modal "submit" is not set (not sure how to go about this either).

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):

    form = WarehouseForm(request.POST or None)
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None

    if form.is_valid():
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in request.POST:
            new_entry = form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter((Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)) & (Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number__isnull=True))).update(time_in=datetime.now())

            # If employee has an entry without an exit and attempts to enter a new area, mark as an exception 'N'
            enters_without_exits = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_exceptions="")).exclude(pk=new_entry.pk).order_by("-time_in")
            if len(enters_without_exits) > 0:
                enter_without_exit = enters_without_exits[0]
                enters_without_exits.update(time_exceptions='N')

            message = 'You have entered %(area)s' % {'area': area}
            if station is not None:
                message += ': %(station)s' % {'station': station}
            messages.success(request, message)

    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
        'enter_without_exit': enter_without_exit,
    })


class UpdateTimestampModal(CreateUpdateModalView):
    main_model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    model_name = "EmployeeWorkAreaLog"
    form_class = WarehouseForm
    template = 'operations/modals/update_timestamp_modal.html'
    modal_title = 'Update Missing Time'
```

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    edited_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_exceptions = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, default='', choices=EXCEPTION_STATUS)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number', 'edited_timestamp')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', views.enter_exit_area, name='enter_exit_area'),
    url(r'update-timestamp-modal/(?P<main_pk>\d+)/$', UpdateTimestampModal.as_view(), name='update_timestamp_modal'),
]
```

This is included in the main html where the modal is called from:

```
<script src="{% static "js/operations/warehouse_enter_exit.js" %}"></script>

    ...

{% modal id="create-update-modal" title="Update Timestamp" primary_btn="Submit" default_submit=True %}
```

**update_timestamp_modal.html**

```
{% load core_tags %}

<form id="create-update-form" method="post" action="{% url "operations:update_timestamp_modal" main_object.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Update</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            {% standard_input form.edited_timestamp datetimepicker=True %}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**warehouse_enter_exit.js**

```
$(function () {

    // Submit the create competitor form when they click the "Submit" button in the modal
    $(document).on('click', '#update-timestamp-modal-btn-primary', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        forms.ajaxSubmit($('#create-update-form'), function (data) {
            if (data.success && data.redirect) {
                window.location.href = data.redirect;
            } else {
                if (data.warning) {
                    messages.warning(data.warning);
                } else {
                    messages.error("An error occurred when saving this timestamp, please try again.");
                }
            }
        });
    });


});
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript handling the click event of the Submit button? Otherwise the problem is that your button is not within the form which causes the button click to not submit the form.

Comment: @schillingt Sorry, forgot to add my JS!

Comment: Have you verifed that the click handler gets triggered? Also isn't it `$('#create-update-form').ajaxSubmit(successFunction)`?